# Can SwiftUI `ToolbarItem` buttons respect `UINavigationBarAppearance` attributes?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

I am developing a library that can present SwiftUI views within an app. I want my navigation bar elements to respect any appearance proxy configuration of the app. In a prior implementation using UIKit, bar buttons automatically used any appearance proxy configuration (i.e. the font, including color). Here's what I'm observing. Note that "My Button" is not styled.

[image]

The simplified code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    
                    Button {
                        // do something
                    } label: {
                        Text("My Button")
                    }
```

SwiftUI does respect the navigation bar background color and title text attributes specified through the appearance proxy mechanism. However, this doesn't work for buttons.

```
static func configureAppearance() {
        
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .blue
    
    let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        
    navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .blue
                
    var titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]()
    titleTextAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.font] = UIFont(name: "Menlo", size: 14)
    titleTextAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = UIColor.white
        
    navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = titleTextAttributes

    let plainBarButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(style: .plain)
    plainBarButtonItemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = titleTextAttributes
    
    navigationBarAppearance.buttonAppearance = plainBarButtonItemAppearance
    
    let doneBarButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(style: .done)
    doneBarButtonItemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = titleTextAttributes
    navigationBarAppearance.doneButtonAppearance = doneBarButtonItemAppearance
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
}
```

Is there some simple way to instruct SwiftUI to allow buttons to participate in the appearance proxy configuration?

I realize that I could manually read attributes from the `UINavigationBar.appearance()` and construct the analogous customizations in SwiftUI, but this seems unnecessarily tedious.

Using Xcode 14.3 on iOS 16.4

Comment: Apple seems to be moving away from these modifiers working at all. I wouldn’t base an app on them